# A way to connect to a program hosted on a computer via website

Tags: c#, php, javascript, c++, ajax

What would be a good way to connect to a program hosted on a computer just to check if it's online on a website.

Example: on the website if online = true show tick else show cross,

What would be a good programming language for this?

Comment: Take your pick... Seems like any language would be fine.

Comment: you should also define some parameters for the program.  Can this be a web page? Windows only? Linux only? Mac only? Multi-platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any language that has support to sockets will do. (That is, in some form or another, pretty much all of them).

As for monitoring the application, it depends on what kind of application it is.

If this application has a network connection (ie. an open port waiting for a connection), you can just try to connected there.

If it doesn't, you would need to have a daemon/service-like application running on the same machine (or network, that depends on the OS said machine is using) listening to such connection from your website and reporting whether the application is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any modern language can do this.